# Status bar overlay image shifted down in android nought

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, statusbar, android-7.0-nougat

I am trying to add an image to the status bar in xamarin forms android..
But the image is completely shifted down and coming under the normal status bar color i set in android nougat.

This happened when i updated the xamarin forms version to 2.4.0.74863
in 2.3.4.270 its working fine. Is this the xamrin forms issue or my code issue.

The code i used to draw overlay on status bar is

```
activity.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
                activity.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
                activity.Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);

ViewGroup contentView = (ViewGroup)activity.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
            //if (contentView.ChildCount > 1)
            //{
            //  contentView.RemoveViewAt(1);
            //}

            // get status bar height
            int res = activity.Resources.GetIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
            int height = 0;
            if (res != 0)
                height = activity.Resources.GetDimensionPixelSize(res);


            // create new imageview and set resource id
            ImageView image = new ImageView(activity);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, height);
            params1.Width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent;
            image.LayoutParameters = params1;
            image.SetImageResource(imageRes);

            image.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FitXy);

            // add image view to content view
            contentView.AddView(image);
            contentView.SetFitsSystemWindows(true);
```

I call this as a dependedncy from the xaml page.

**EDIT**

After i added the flags that @york mentioned the bottom navigation bar has become translucent and the app view went down.

[image: Bottom navigation bar]

Comment: I have test your code in my `Xamarin.Forms` project, my version code is 2.4.0.74863 and it works fine on myside, could you please share a basic demo to reproduce this problem ? To make sure we are verifying the exact same thing you are using.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT can you please check code in https://github.com/georgethms10/XamarinStatusBarSample

Comment: Apply `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your root layout.

Comment: i have added contentView.SetFitsSystemWindows(true); still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need add the following code in your `Activity` style :

```
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Effect :

[image]

Comment: when i added  <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item> the bottom navigation bar become translucent and the app screen went down any way we could fix it

Comment: can you please check the Edit in the question

Comment: @GeorgeThomas, how did you write the bottom navigation bar? Please post your code, and could you please post a more complete picture ?